# Binding With Multiple Tables Spring Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, jpa, data-binding, thymeleaf

I know the title of this question is not clear, but before disliking let me explain my problem.

I have a social media with java spring using JPA and thymeleaf.

Users have ids, usernames, and creation dates.

In the posts table there is a field called "authorid", so when someone makes a new post the system only writes his user id, not his username.

Now, I have a page on the site, available at "localhost:8080/showAllPosts/" which shows ALL the application posts from the most recent to the least recent. The controller looks something like this:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

  @GetMapping("/showAllPosts") 
  public String showAllPosts(Model model) {

    List<Post> post = new ArrayList<>();
    model.addAttribute("post", post);

    List<Post> posts = postRepository.findAll();
    model.addAttibute("posts", posts);

    return "showallposts.html";
  }
}
```

The showallposts.html page looks like this:

```
<table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr th:if="${posts.empty}">
                            <td colspan="2">No Posts Available</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr th:each="post : ${posts}">
                            <td>                                
<span th:text="'posted by ' + ${post.authorid}>
                                <span th:text="${post.postcontent}"></span>
                                <br>                                
                            </td>
                            <td>                            
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

As you can see, it shows the post content, and "posted by" plus the author. The only problem is that the `post.authorid` returns the numeric id of user who posted, and I wanted the username. Is there something we can do with the users model?

Notice that in the users repository I have this method:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT u.username FROM Users u WHERE u.userid = ?1")
public String findUsernameById(Long userid);
```

ALL help is appreciated! <3

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use a DTO to move the post with the author's name into the Thymeleaf view.

1. Create a new class like PostDto:

```java
public class PostDto {
    private Long id;
    private String postContent;
    private Long authorId;
    private String String authorName;

    // other fields
    // getters and setters
}
```

2. Convert your post entity class to PostDto using the Stream API. During the mapping, you can get the username by authorId via UserRespository and supplement the post dto object with the author's name.

```java
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping("/showAllPosts") 
    public String showAllPosts(Model model) {
        List<Post> post = new ArrayList<>();

        model.addAttribute("post", post);

        List<Post> posts = postRepository.findAll().stream()
            .map(post -> {
                PostDto dto = toDto(post);
                dto.setAuthorName(userRepository.findUsernameById(post.getAuthorId()));
            })

        model.addAttibute("posts", posts);

        return "showallposts.html";
    }


    private PostDto toDto(Post post) {
        PostDto dto = new PostDto();
        dto.setId(post.getId);
        dto.setPostContent(post.getPostContent());
        dto.setAuthorId(post.getAuthorId());
    }
}
```

3. Use in the Thymeleaf view as `${post.authorName}`.

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr th:if="${posts.empty}">
            <td colspan="2">No Posts Available</td>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="post : ${posts}">
            <td>
                <span th:text="'posted by ' + ${post.authorName}>
                <span th:text="${post.postcontent}"></span>
                <br> 
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi  @mamadaliev, first of all thanks for your answer and for sharing working knowledge. Everything is working fine, but in the MyController class the code you proposed gives an error, when streaming for the List<Posts> object. The error is: Multiple markers at this line
 - Lambda expression's parameter post cannot redeclare 
  another local variable defined in an enclosing scope.
 - The method map(Function<? super Post,? extends R>) in 
  the type Stream<Post> is not applicable for the arguments ((<no 
  type> post) -> {}).

Comment: please. answer.